# Getting Unknown provider error for resolved value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have this simple Router:

```
    .when('/login/:uuid', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'RoomLoginCtrl',
            resolve: {
              roomName: function($route, ServerService) {
                var uuid = $route.current.params.uuid;
                return ServerService.getRoomName(uuid); //returns promise
              }
            }
          })
....
```

And here is the controller:

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('app')
    .controller('RoomLoginCtrl', RoomLoginCtrl);

  function RoomLoginCtrl($location, TransferService, roomName) {
    var vm  = this;
    vm.$location = $location;
    vm.TransferService = TransferService;
    vm.roomName = roomName;
    vm.userName = "";
  }
})(angular);
```

My problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: roomNameProvider <- roomName <- RoomLoginCtrl
```

The odd thing is that when I debug I can see that `roomName` is getting the resolved value. The app crashes later, not other operation done (not that I know of it).

Why this thing is crushing?

Thanks!

Comment: there is a controllerAs:'vm'  missing in your routing . vm or a other name you use in your view

Comment: Did you specify `ng-controller="RoomLoginCtrl"` in `views/login.html`? That invocation of the controller would not get `roomName` injected

Comment: Try change return to `return ServerService.getRoomName(uuid).$promise;`  (`.$promise` added to end)

Comment: Thanks you, I have used your suggestion to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From mixing both @micha's and @New Dev's comments I solved it by doing as follow:

added `controllerAs: 'vm'`:

```
.when('/login/:uuid', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'RoomLoginCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
            resolve: {
              roomName: function($route, ServerService) {
                var uuid = $route.current.params.uuid;
                return ServerService.getRoomName(uuid); //returns promise
              }
            }
})
```

And also removed the `ng-controller="RoomLoginCtrl as vm"` from the `temolateUrl` tag:
Changed this:

```
<div ng-controller="RoomLoginCtrl as vm">
```

To this:

```
<div>
```

Thanks for the help!